# Is there an argument I can feed to my phpunit command to force emission of a stack trace?

Tags: php, exception, phpunit, stack-trace, raml

I am running a command like this:

```
phpunit path/to/my/testSet.raml
```

... and I'm finding that I get a rather opaque message about expecting a 201 but getting a 500. No stack trace is given.

Is there an argument that I can feed to my phpunit command that will cause it to emit a stack trace when there is a problem?

Comment: Is there no error log from the application you're testing?

Comment: Not that I can see. But you make a good point: This may be an application-level problem rather than a PHPUnit problem

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is pure PHPUnit or not, but try `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` at the beginning of your test, that should throw the exception instead of giving you the assertion error

---

This may only work on Laravel, but I am not sure, just give it a try